# useState changing doesn't update in the function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a state and a function that goes like this

```
  const [like, setLike] = useState(false);

  const likeOperation = () => {
    setLike(!like);

    if (like) {
      console.log('like is ' + like);
    }
  };
```

Like is false at first, then I set it to true with the !like operator.
But then in my if block, like is still false and I get no console.log unless I click it again.

Is that normal behavior?

And is the following code good practice?

```
  const [like, setLike] = useState(false);
  const [dislike, setDislike] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (like && dislike) {
      setDislike(false);
    }
  }, [like]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (dislike && like) {
      setLike(false);
    }
  }, [dislike]);

  const likeOperation = (operation = 'like') => {
    if (operation === 'like') {
      setLike(!like);
    }

    if (operation === 'dislike') {
      setDislike(!dislike);
    }
  };
```

Comment: The value of like doesn't change until the assignment is reached again, next time the component is rendered.

Answer (score 1):

`setLike` is async and you cannot check `like` status immediately after. You have to use a temp variable like:

```
const [like, setLike] = useState(false);

  const likeOperation = () => {
    let result = !like;
    setLike(result);

    if (result) {
      console.log('like is ' + result );
    }
  };
```

EDIT:

Just a suggestion for code you added: when you read state inside `useEffect` hook, every state variables must be added to `useEffect`'s deps list. So I suggest you to change your code like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (like && dislike) {
      setDislike(false);
    }
  }, [like, dislike]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (dislike && like) {
      setLike(false);
    }
  }, [dislike, like]);
```

Otehrwise you got a warning from React.

Comment: Yes unfortunately. And the bad thing is that with hook you don't have callback neither (like it was with old react). So the only way to check state value after set is to use a temp valriable. Infact there is another way: use useEffect hook (like Viet and Gucal suggested).

Comment: @ΚωνσταντινοςΤζιανακουλης I updated my answer with one suggestion for the last code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

`setLike` is is asynchronous. If you want to check when like change, you can use `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {...your logic }, [like])
```

Comment: Thanks, is that the best solution?

Comment: Yes. This is the best solution